# How to measure the execution time of each SQL statement query in SQLite

Tags: sqlite

I want to check the query execution time (Not using .timer on)
I want to measure the each SQL Statement execution time.
I think I can use the Gettimeofday function.
But I can't know what is the "start/end" point of each SQL query.

In shorts,
- What is the start/end point during query execution 
- How can I measure the each query execution time ? ( Not using .timer option)

Comment: Are you accessing the database from the `sqlite3` command line shell, or your own program?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

if you are using OS X, i recommend you use time (using the command line in Terminal) to measure the execution time of the query. It is by far the easiest way:

```
time printf "<your query>;" | sqlite3 databaseFile.db > /dev/null
```

Example:

```
time printf "select * from blame;" | sqlite3 mydata.db > /dev/null 

real    0m1.603s
user    0m1.167s
sys     0m0.112s
```

the command also works under linux. We pipe the output to /dev/null to avoid any waste of time due to saving/printing the output.

There is some overhead of opening the database connection and loading the executable, but it will give you a good idea in terms of how expensive (in terms of time) your query.

You can get an idea of that overhead by doing something like this:

```
time printf ".schema" | sqlite3 mydata.db > /dev/null
```

If you want to get a better understanding of what is going on, I recommend you look into the command explain. In sqlite3 do:

```
explain select * from table;
```

and you will get a full explanation of the operations sqlite is expecting to do to compute a query.